# What crashed Automake?

Tags: linux, php, open-source, compile, cross-platform

When downloading open-source software from the internet (in this case: PHP 5.5.5), they often come with an Automake "script" (if I can call it a script) for building from source.

Now I'm trying to cross-compile for a different architecture, but I keep getting a different error whenever I specify a different ./configure --switch. Typically, this error is a short non-descriptive message that means absolutely nothing to anyone except the developer.

> checking "whether flock struct is linux ordered"... configure: error: in `/usr/src/hd/lib/php-5.5.5':
> configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling

Followed by:

> See `config.log' for more details

So I type:

> cat ./config.log

But really, the only thing out of the ordinary that it's showing me is this:

> configure: exit 1

--

So what gives? How can I tell what the problem is?

FYI, my configure options look somewhat like this:

```
./configure --prefix="`pwd`/install/" \
--build="i386-pc-linux-gnu" \
--host="mips-linux-gnu" \
--target="mips-linux-gnu" \
--with-libxml-dir="/usr/src/hd/lib/libxml2-2.7.8/install/" \
--enable-soap \
CC="mips-linux-gnu-gcc" \
CFLAGS="-O2 -EL -march=74kf" \
CPP="mips-linux-gnu-cpp" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$CROSS_ROOTFS/include" \
CXX="mips-linux-gnu-g++" \
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -EL -march=74kf" \
CXXCPP="mips-linux-gnu-cpp" \
AR="mips-linux-gnu-ar" \
RANLIB="mips-linux-gnu-ranlib" \
AS="mips-linux-gnu-as" \
NM="mips-linux-gnu-nm" \
LD="mips-linux-gnu-ld" \
LDFLAGS="-L$CROSS_ROOTFS/lib" \
ADDR2LINE="mips-linux-gnu-addr2line"
```

As you may not know, I'm using the CodeSourcery toolchain to cross-compile for mips. I am aware that I don't need to specify all of the variables (such as RANLIB), but I don't see how it could hurt.

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to lie in one (or more) of the bundled extensions, as listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.membership.php

Configuring with --disable-all works. But obviously, I do need at least some of those bundled extensions in order to do some real work.

Still, how can I tell which one?

**UPDATE**

I narrowed the problem down to an extension called OPcache that was enabled by default (see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php). It successfully compiled after disabling that, along with some other extensions that wouldn't work on my target system anyway.

Still, this was not obvious to me at all. What I did was work my way backwards from the output log, disabling listed extensions one by one until the stupid thing would finally work.

Surely there has to exist a better way to pinpoint problems like these? Otherwise what the hell is the entire point of this automake nonsense?

Comment: You've done well. Rather than enabling the extensions one-by-one, try a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Maybe I'm just not experienced enough to understand where autoconfig fits in the world of open-source, but to me it seems like one of the dumbest ideas ever conceived. Then again, the PHP guys do state that they do not/will not support cross-compiling. These problems didn't come as a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

The `opscache` requires `libtdl`, which is part of [GNU Libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/libtool.html).

### Linux

On Linux, get the `libltdl-dev` package, for example on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev
```

### Mac OSX

For OSX, the easiest way to install GNU Libtool is to install it through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
$ brew install libtool
```

Specifically, GNU Libtool will provide the following files which is used for PHP compilation

```
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.a
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
```

As a side note, OSX ships with its own copy of libtool which does not include libtdl interface. To avoid conflicts, GNU Libtool tools are prefixed with 'g', e.g. `glibtool` and `glibtoolize`

### Libtdl

For more information, please refer to http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libltdl-interface.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently still using PHP without OPcache, but I'll look into this. I do have to ask, where do you find this sort of information? I don't recall libdtl being referenced anywhere, ever.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I got lucky - was searching with the error message, specifically around `struct flock` and stumbled upon vasilis' solution at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65423 . I'm hoping the PHP devs will either add libtool as dep when opcache's enabled, or give a more useful `autoconf` / `make` error message. I've also submitted a similar patch for https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/ PHP >5.5 and hope it gets accepted